# PineScript Variables Intermittent Vales during candle making

Tags: charts, pine-script, trading, technical-indicator

I have a question regarding variables value during pine script execution.

Below picture shows a scenario on a five minute chart. In the first candle 11.00 am, the close price is 9200. New candle starts at 11.05 am and this candle is in making. Initially the price is 9100 and then changes to 8900, 9150, 9500 and 9300.

Inside the pinescript script there is a boolean "var lessthan9K" which stores the latest value. This variable is set to true if value goes less than 9000. This value remains true till other condition is met - Greater than 10000. It becomes false when value goes above 10000.

When new candle is in making and when price goes to 8900 at 11.06 am, lessthan9k variable becomes true. My question is whether this value remains true end of the candle when final close price is 9300 @ 11.09 am or it resets to false?

Basically how does it work ? During the candle making, any intermittent values are stored or lost (from 1 to 5)?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call *intermittent values* are lost because of the rollback process in the realtime bar. See the usrman's [Calculation based on realtime bars](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#calculation-based-on-realtime-bars) section for an explanation.

Comment: okay in that case what will happen if a "buy" alert was fired in the middle of the realtime bar but that condition is not true when realtime bar is done? Also, if there is a position variable to keep track of position so that later "sell" alert can be generated in future. If value is lost, is there any way for pinescript or us to know that buy alert has been sent earlier (but now that is not reflecting in the chart) ? Please advise. Sorry for troubling you but am trying to make this scenario work. Thanks

Comment: You can prevent unconfirmed alerts by configuring your alerts to only trigger "Once Per Bar Close". If you really need the 1min resolution to make decisions, then your script and alerts need to run on a 1min chart.

Comment: hi pinecoders, now tv is allowing alerts on strategies. do u know if there is any way to know if buy alert is fired based on condition that doesn't hold true end of the realtime candle ? I mean by using position or something else?

Comment: Hi, You can customize the message sent with the new strategy alerts, and contrary to `alertcondition()` messages, strategy `comment=` and `alert_message=` arguments can contain dynamic text, so you can personalize the alert messages to the precise conditions triggering them, which could be a condition detected during the realtime bar, provided your strategy is using `calc_on_every_tick = true`.

Comment: hi pinecoders : one last question regarding this. If calc_on_every_tick is true and there is a scenario where price update is more frequent than normal (heavy selling or buying), if pine script takes long time to execute say 2 sec and price update is every 1 sec, what happens in that scenario?